# Interface Builder and Cocoa: wiring up behind an App Controller class

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos, interface-builder

I have been following [this](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/IB_UserGuide/QuickStart/QuickStart.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40005344-CH22-SW27) tutorial. I'm having conceptual trouble at the point where an App Controller class is written, and then added and hooked up within Interface Builder.

> Adding the AppController Class 
>   The next task is to add an instance of the
>   new class to the Interface Builder
>   document and connect the class
>   outlets.
>
> Create an instance of the
>   AppController class. In the Interface
>   Builder Library window, click Classes.
>   Locate the AppController class. Drag
>   this class into the document window to
>   create an instance named App
>   Controller. Connect the App
>   Controller’s qcWindow outlet to the
>   design window. Hold down the Control
>   key. In the document window, drag from
>   the App Controller to the Window
>   object. Select the qcWindow outlet
>   from the list that appears. Connect
>   the App Controller’s qcView outlet to
>   the QC view in the design window. Hold
>   down the Control key. Drag from the
>   App Controller to the QC view in the
>   design window. Select the qcView
>   outlet from the list that appears.

Specifically, I don't understand how this App Controller is being used at run-time. All I did was hook up the window and view outlets within IB, and it magically works as if it was being initialized within the `applicationDidFinishLaunching:aNotification` method of my app delegate. My point is, I'm not using my App Controller class anywhere in my code, and all I've done in IB is hook up its outlets, so how does it work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When your application is launched, a shared instance of [NSApplication](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html) is created and [MainMenu.xib/nib is loaded](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/LoadingResources/CocoaNibs/CocoaNibs.html) and its contents (including the main menu itself) are hooked up. During this loading processs, the NSApp instance's delegate is pointed at your "un-freeze-dried" (unarchived) class, which (among other possible things) can answer NSApp delegate questions and can then begin messaging it (and relying on it for App-wide behavioral customizations).

One useful aspect of all this is that you can access the delegate from anywhere in your app via `[NSApp delegate]`, which is short for `[[NSApplication sharedApplication] delegate]`. This is extremely handy for navigating parts of your architecture if you hang them off your app delegate and provide accessors for them (like `[[NSApp delegate] fooController]`).